# Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be monotone. Then the set of points, at which it is discontinuous, is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation

Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be monotone. Then the set of points, at which it is discontinuous, is countable.

The solution given goes like this:

Let $D$ denote the set of discontinuity points. For each $x\in D$, the left and right limits differ, and are therefore the endpoints of a non-empty open interval. In this manner we obtain a collection of such intervals
$$
\{I_d\colon d\in D\}.
$$
By monotonicity the intervals are disjoint. Choosing one rational number from each interval therefore yields an injection from $D$ into $\mathbb Q$. Hence $D$ is countable.

---

However, I don't get two things:

- How do they write, "By monotonicity the intervals are disjoint". I don't understand how does the monotonicity gurantees that the intervals are disjoint. Am I missing something?
- Finally, when i gazed through the proof completely, I felt that the line, "For each $x\in D$, the left and right limits differ, and are therefore the endpoints of a non-empty open interval." need  not be true. It may so happen that the left-hand and right hand limits at a point are equal but it not equal to the value of $f$ at that point. This can be just yet another possibility for $f$ to be discontinuous at that point. So, isn't proof somewhat incomplete because of this?

Comment: I don't quite get the reason for the downvote? Is something wrong with my post?

Comment: Yes. It consists of two questions posted together.

Comment: @AnotherUser But two questions interrelated with one another and on tge same topic so the downvote seems quite questionable. If I had posted these two questions separately, it would unnecessarily clutter up the site.  *Plus, this is a proof-explanation question and it seems absurd to post each doubt about the proof separately!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is monotonically increasing.Let us write $f(x+)$ and $f(x-)$ for the right-hand and left-hand limits of $f$ at $x$.

Consider two points $a, b \in D$ with $a <b$. What the proof says is $(f(a-),f(a+)$ and $(f(b-),f(b+)$ are disjoint.

If the two intervals are not disjoint then there is a number $c$ with  $f(b-)<c<f(a+)$. But then $f(b-r)<c<f(a+r)$ for $r>0$ sufficiently small. Since we can choose $r$ with $a+r<b-r$ we get a  contradiction to the fact that $f$ is monotonically increasing.

For your second question just note that if $f$ is monotonically increasing function then, we have, $f(c-)\leq f(c)\leq f(c+).$

If $f(c+)=f(c-)$ and $f$ is monotonic then necessarily $f(c)=f(c+)=f(c-)$.

If $f$ is monotonically decreasing we can apply the argument to $-f$: Note that $f$ and $-f$ have the same points of continuity. (Or, we can do the same by using the inequality $f(c+)\leq f(c)\leq f(c-)$ for a monotonically decreasing function.)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! I have just edited my OP just to include another question. Will you please mind taking a look at it?

Comment: @ThomasFinley That cannot happen for a monotonic function: If $f$ is increasing then $f(x-)\leq f(x)\leq f(x+)$ always.

Comment: Isn't the inequality true for a monotonic increasing function?

Comment: That is what I said. If $f(x-)=f(x+)$ then we get $f(x-)=f(x)=f(x+)$, so $x$ is not a point of dis-continuity. [For the case when $f$ is monotonically decreasing just apply the argument to $-f$ which as the same points of dis-continuity as $f$ .

Comment: ok, and for a monotonically decreasing function, we have the inequality, $f(c+)\leq f(c)\leq f(c-).$ I will be glad to accept your answer, if you consider adding this two statements about inequalities in your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasFinley I have edited.

Comment: I made a little modification to your answer by adding two more lines of reasoning and improved the readability a bit. Is it ok with you? Btw, +1 from me. I accepted your answer!

Comment: Yes, what you have done is fine with me. Thanks for the approval. @ThomasFinley

Comment: Thanks! No problem.